# How does the field access behave after cloning a constant map in Ballerina

Tags: clone, readonly, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

Consider the following code:

```
import ballerina/io;

type User record {|
    string name;
    string email;
|};

const USER = {
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john.doe@gmail.com"
};

public function main() {
    User user = USER.clone();
    user.name = "Jane Doe";
    io:println("User name: " + user.name);
}
```

Is this code correct? I have a constant map and clone it as user and updated one field. Since it is a clone with a constant map, are the fields cloned as readonly? Then the clone() should return a compiler error, since in the target type, the field is not explicitly readonly right?

Currently this is failing with this runtime error:

```
error: {ballerina/lang.map}InherentTypeViolation {"message":"cannot update 'readonly' field 'name' in record of type '(service:record {| "John Doe" name; "john.doe@gmail.com" email; |} & readonly)'"}
```

But if I use cloneWithType() it is working fine:

```
public function main() returns error? {
    User user = check USER.cloneWithType();
    user.name = "Jane Doe";
    io:println("User name: " + user.name);
}
```

Can someone explain the behaviour here?

Answer (score 1):

In here the type of the USER  is inferred as

```
{
    name: "John Doe",
    email: "john.doe@gmail.com"
} & readonly
```

by the Ballerina compiler.

The USER.clone() will return the `USER` record itself since it is immutable.

So, the type of USER is a subtype of `User` record. So Compiler allows to assign that into the user variable. But the original type of the `USER` record is readonly.
So we cannot update the fields of the record(We can't update fields in readonly maps). That is the meaning of the error message.

Example:-
Assume there is a type called A.

```
A & readonly a = value

A b = a
```

In here the type of the b is A & readonly
So we cannot update the fields in value b

But if you use CloneWithType function, It will clone the value and convert it into the expected type.

So in here the type of the user is User.

```
User user = check USER.cloneWithType();
```

So we can update the fields in here.

By the way important to know that when you use clone() (or cloneReadOnly()) with an immutable value a copy will not be created. The value itself will be the result.

```
User user = USER.clone();
io:println(user == USER); // true

User & readonly userImmutable = USER.cloneReadOnly();
io:println(userImmutable == USER); // true
```